what is the model of noise on the RSSI data collected from cellular networks?
I have two questions:
1.) In the RSSI data (received power data) collected from real urban environments in cellular networks, is the noise typically modeled as linear Gaussian or non-linear Gaussian noise?
2.) What is the best solution for reducing this noise?
